# how to add ui-sref in dynamic html template?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-sref

I need to add dynamic template on click for that i have used :

```
var action_template='';
app.controller('EventCtrl',function($rootScope){
     action_template =  action_template +'<ul><li><a ui-sref="/root/authenticate"><img src="default.png"></a></li></ul>';                  
   $rootScope.template=action_template;  
});
```

In html:i have used ngSanitize

```
<ul>
       <li ng-bind-html="template"></li> 
</ul>
```

template is appending perfectly but there is no href link.

what I am doing wrong ? Or is there any solution for doing the same thing ?

The main problem was unable to add any angular directives such as ng-click, ng-href, ui-sref etc.
But after adding $sce.trustAsHtml it is adding ui-sref but not adding any hyperlink.

Hint will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're using $rootScope instead of $scope?

Comment: Try $rootScope.template=$sce.trustAsHtml(action_template);. Don't forget to inject $sce in your controller

Answer (score 2):

I think you forgot **trustAsHtml** in your controller(you can see in the snippet after running, that ui-sref is present in the source):-

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
var action_template='';
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$rootScope,$sce) {
  
   action_template =  action_template +'<ul><li><a ui-sref="/root/authenticate">Link</a></li></ul>';                  
   $rootScope.template=$sce.trustAsHtml(action_template);  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  
<ul>
       <li ng-bind-html="template"></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need trust your HTML, using `$sce`, Try below code

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);
jimApp.controller('EventCtrl',function($rootScope, $sce, $scope){
     var action_template='';
     action_template =  action_template +'<ul><li><a ui-sref="/root/authenticate"><img src="default.png" alt="Default image">Link</a></li></ul>';                  
   $scope.template=$sce.trustAsHtml(action_template);  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="EventCtrl">
<ul>
       <li ng-bind-html="template"></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: now , ui-sref is present but it is not adding any href link , why so ? please see my updated question.

Comment: @user7390851 i didn't understand what you mean

Comment: after adding $sce.trustAsHtml it is giving like this : 
<a ui-sref="/root/authenticate"></a> 
but it should be like
<a ui-sref="/root/authenticate" href="/root/authenticate"></a>
means auto href will be added automatically.

Comment: It's not a problem , angular automatically adding the href when you use ui-sref